# Rails and named_scope queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm trying to get my head around the concept of named_scoped queries in rails.
I'm trying to filter a table to get only non featured items (:featured => false).

In my model i have added

scope :allgames, where(:featured => false)
and 
scope :featured, where(featured => true)

I'm trying to list all featured and non featured items separately on my Game index page.

Is it possible to to it via a named scope.

So far i have:

```
<% @games.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.featured %> 
    <%= render 'application/item_synopsis_builder', item: item %>
  <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

And I wonder if it is possible to do something like:

```
<% @games.featured.each do |item| %>
    <%= render 'application/item_synopsis_builder', item: item %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= render partial: 'application/item_synopsis_builder', collection: @games.featured %>
```

When I try I get a message saying that there is no method featured.
But when I run the command `Game.featured` in the console I get the result list of all featured games.

Is it possible to access this list/method in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named scopes are added to the model as a class method, so trying to access the method on a collection of objects won't work.  Similar functionality can be achieved with:

```
    @games.where(:featured => true).each do 
       ...
    end
```

But I would recommend having two variables in your controller:

```
    @featured_games = Games.featured
    @all_games      = Games.allgames
```

then use those in your views.

Comment: Yop I just tried that in the controller and it works fine. Just thought it was possible to access it straigth fronthe view. Anyway, that's just awesome. Thanks for your help

Comment: To do this directly in the view, use Games.featured in the view, instead of setting an instance variable in the controller.  <% Games.featured.each do |item| %>

Comment: The proper place for data access is in the controller. While you can do an ActiveRecord find in views or helpers it is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Your views are driven by the @games instance variable that is created by the controller that is rendering the views. Named scopes create a class method for subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base. So "Game.featured" returns something because defining the named scope created a method for the Game class. It did **not** create an instance method that objects of the Game class (such as @games) can invoke. That's why "@games.featured" gives you an error.

To do what you want to do, create two instance variable in the controller and pass them to the view, e.g.

```
@all_games = Game.allgames
@featured_games = Game.featured
```

Both variables will be available to your view, and you can construct loops to render each collection however you like.

Comment: Damn you, simultaneous posting!

Answer (score 0):

A scope is a class method (or assimilable to, I don't know the specifics), so yes, Game.featured would work, but when you do @games.featured, you are calling `featured` on an array of `Game` instances.